# shortcode not working after migration

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I wrote my own plugin to display some information in a dynamic way. Everything worked perfectly on my localhost but when i did the migration to the server the shortcode of my plugin(and only that one) is displayed as text.

I checked and the plugin is still activated.

this is my plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: video-linker
Plugin URI: http://example.com
Description: Youku, Youtube and Vimeo linker
Version: 1.0
Author: Arno Turelinckx
Author URI: http://example.com
*/

$youku = '';
$youtube = '';
$vimeo = '';
$image = '';

function visualize_buttons($atts) {

    //get the links from the shortcode
    $attributes = shortcode_atts( array(
        'youku' => '',
        'youtube' => '',
        'vimeo' => '',
        'image' => '',
    ), $atts );

    $youku = $attributes['youku'];
    $youtube = $attributes['youtube'];
    $vimeo = $attributes['vimeo'];
    $image = $attributes['image'];

    echo '<div style="position: relative;">';
        echo '<div class="video-linker-image" style="background-image: url('.$image.');background-size: cover;"></div>';
        echo '<ul class="video-linker">';
            echo '<h2>Watch the video</h2>';
            echo '<li class="video-linker-youku"><a href="'.$youku.'" target="_blank"></a></li>';
            echo '<li class="video-linker-youtube"><a href="'.$youtube.'" target="_blank"><i class="icon-youtube"></i></a></li>';
            echo '<li class="video-linker-vimeo"><a href="'.$vimeo.'" target="_blank"><i class="icon-vimeo"></i></a></li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
}

function cf_shortcode($atts) {
    ob_start();
    visualize_buttons($atts);

    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'video-linker', 'cf_shortcode' );

?>
```

And this is the way I call the shortcode in my page:

> [video-linker youku=”” youtube=”” vimeo=”” image=”url_to_image.jpg”]

Any idea what the problem could be?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using output buffering? Any special reason for it?

Comment: It is my first time i created a plugin, the tutorial told me to use it

Comment: I think that you can do it without ob. Look the official pages of [`add_shortcode()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode). No output buffering there...

Comment: Okay, I just deleted it. But this still doesn't fix my problems :/
Do you have any other tips?

Comment: Upvoted due to an almost excellent written shortcode. Just on output buffering, shortcodes should never echo its output, it should always be returned. Your function echo's output, which does not go well with shortcodes. What output buffering is doing is, it catches that output before it displays on screen and rather than displaying that output, it returns it so it can be used in a shortcode

Comment: @dingo_d see my comment above on output buffering.

Comment: Did you make sure that your plugin is activated. You must reactivate the plugin after migration.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code. This should work, I put it in wentysixteen in `functions.php` and it worked:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: video-linker
Plugin URI: http://example.com
Description: Youku, Youtube and Vimeo linker
Version: 1.0
Author: Arno Turelinckx
Author URI: http://example.com
*/

    function cf_shortcode($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts( array(
        'youku' => '',
        'youtube' => '',
        'vimeo' => '',
        'image' => '',
    ), $atts));


    $youku   = isset( $atts['youku'] ) ? $atts['youku'] : '';
    $youtube = isset( $atts['youtube'] ) ? $atts['youtube'] : '';
    $vimeo   = isset( $atts['vimeo'] ) ? $atts['vimeo'] : '';
    $image   = isset( $atts['image'] ) ? $atts['image'] : '';

    $return = '<div style="position: relative;">';
    $return .= ($image != '') ? '<div class="video-linker-image" style="background-image: url('.esc_url($image).');background-size: cover;"></div>' : '';
    $return .= '<ul class="video-linker">
            <h2>Watch the video</h2>';
    $return .= ($youku != '') ? '<li class="video-linker-youku"><a href="'.esc_url($youku).'" target="_blank"></a></li>' : '';
    $return .= ($youtube != '') ? '<li class="video-linker-youtube"><a href="'.esc_url($youtube).'" target="_blank"><i class="icon-youtube"></i></a></li>' : '';
    $return .= ($vimeo != '') ? '<li class="video-linker-vimeo"><a href="'.esc_url($vimeo).'" target="_blank"><i class="icon-vimeo"></i></a></li>' : '';
    $return .= '</ul>
        </div>';
    return $return;
}

add_shortcode( 'video_linker', 'cf_shortcode' );
```

Comment: unfortunately, still no change :(

Comment: I updated the code a bit. Try it now. And did you include your shortcode file from your plugin base with `include_once 'shortcode.php';` (assuming that the above is in the `shortcode.php` file)?

Comment: the code above is my plugin code, could you tell me how to link it? On my localhost that wasn't necessary. sorry for my stupidity.

Comment: Just a note here, I was also not a big fan of output buffering, until I ran some tests, output buffering is much faster than string concatenation. ;-)

Comment: If this is your plugin code, then you shouldn't link anything, but be sure you activated your plugin. @Pieter good to know (even though I remember you saying on one occasion not to use ob :D)

Comment: so any ideas why it isn't working?
It is activated ;)

Comment: Ok, return your old code, but instead of echoing do the return like in my example.

Comment: sorry for my late  response,
I ran a test, and still not working when i return the output :/
any other suggestions?

Comment: I changed the code, can you test the newest version? I tested it in twentysixteen and it works.

Comment: doesn't seem to work...
Could it have something to do with the server?

Comment: Well that's the last thing that could be the issue. Are you sure that there isn't anything in DOM, but is somehow hidden? Did you inspect the page where this should be? Also enable [debug in wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)